# What is the word instead of "valley"

Tags: reference-request, terminology

I have a plot as below, there is a "valley" in it. But I know the word *valley* is not suitable for my plot which has scientific details. What is the best word for describing the *z* component behavior versus *x* and *y* components?  The shape of the valley is shown in the photo at the bottom.

[image: 3-dimensional plot]

[image: photograph of glacial valley]

Comment: You could give a sort of schematic description in terms of derivatives. You have a plane and a function defined on this plane. There is a curve (in this case it looks like a line segment) in the plane. Along this curve, the tangential first and second derivatives are both small, the normal first derivative is also small, and the normal second derivative is large and positive. "Valley" is a perfectly clear name for this concept to me (indeed I have seen a formal usage of the word "valley" in one mathematical context, which is quite closely related to this situation).

Comment: Thank you so much, you ensure me that the selected word is a suitable word. This plot is extracted of numerical outputs, they don't have a precise formula for being gotten derivative!

Comment: Sure, you don't have analytical derivatives, but if your data is supposed to be sampled from some underlying smooth function, then the smooth function has derivatives. Even if not, the data has discrete derivatives.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with using *valley* in this context. It is a visual metaphor which will be readily understood.

An alternative word might be *trough*, which is a bit more common in this abstract sense; but is still a visual metaphor.